# C# Entity Framework: problems with Enumarating entities using custom IQueryable implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I use .NET Framework 4.8 and Entity Framework 6.2.

I have an `IOrderedQueryable` implementation:

```
public sealed class EFQueryable<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>
{
    private static readonly Type _type = typeof(T);
    private readonly IEFQueryProvider _provider;

    public Type ElementType => _type;

    public Expression Expression { get; }

    public IQueryProvider Provider => _provider;

    public EFQueryable(IEFQueryProvider queryProvider)
    {
        _provider = queryProvider;
        Expression = Expression.Constant(this);
    }

    public EFQueryable(IEFQueryProvider queryProvider, Expression expression)
    {
        _provider = queryProvider;
        Expression = expression;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _provider.GetEnumerator<T>(Expression);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _provider.GetEnumerator(Expression);
}
```

This is the `IQueryProvider` interface:

```
public interface IEFQueryProvider : IDbAsyncQueryProvider
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator<T>(Expression expression);

    IEnumerator GetEnumerator(Expression expression);
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public class EFQueryProvider<TEntity> : IEFQueryProvider where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;

    public EFQueryProvider(IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        Type elementType = null;

        try
        {
            elementType = expression.Type.GetGenericArguments().First();
            return (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EFQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType),
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null,
                new object[] { this, expression },
                null,
                null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to create instance of 'RsQueryable<{(elementType ?? expression.Type).Name}>'. {ex.Message}", ex);
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        try
        {
            return new EFQueryable<TElement>(this, expression);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to create instance of '{typeof(EFQueryable<TElement>).Name}'. {ex.Message}", ex);
        }
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                var queryable = db.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
                var convertedExpression = ChangeQueryableInExpression(expression, queryable);

                return queryable.Provider.Execute(convertedExpression);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to query repository. {ex.Message}", ex);
        }
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                var queryable = db.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
                var convertedExpression = ChangeQueryableInExpression(expression, queryable);

                return queryable.Provider.Execute<TResult>(convertedExpression);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to query repository. {ex.Message}", ex);
        }
    }

    public Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Execute(expression), cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Execute<TResult>(expression), cancellationToken);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator<T>(Expression expression)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                var queryable = db.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
                var convertedExpression = ChangeQueryableInExpression(expression, queryable);
                return queryable.Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<T>>(convertedExpression).ToList().GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to query repository. {ex.Message}", ex);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator(Expression expression)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                var queryable = db.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
                var convertedExpression = ChangeQueryableInExpression(expression, queryable);

                return queryable.Provider.Execute<IEnumerable>(convertedExpression).Cast<object>().ToList().GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to query repository. {ex.Message}", ex);
        }
    }

    private static Expression ChangeQueryableInExpression(Expression expression, IQueryable<TEntity> queryable)
    {
        var visitor = new ExpressionQueryableSourceModifier(queryable.Expression);
        return visitor.Visit(expression);
    }

    private sealed class ExpressionQueryableSourceModifier : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Expression _expression;
        private static readonly Type _queryableTypeToReplace = typeof(EFQueryable<TEntity>);

        public ExpressionQueryableSourceModifier(Expression expression)
        {
            _expression = expression;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
        {
            return node.Type == _queryableTypeToReplace ? _expression : base.VisitConstant(node);
        }
    }
}
```

I use `EFQueryable` inside my generic repository. Let's have a look at this method:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> AsQueryable()
{
    return new EFQueryable<TEntity>(new EFQueryProvider<TEntity>(_dbContextFactory));
}
```

and this:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> AsQueryable(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
{
    return AsQueryable().Where(where);
}
```

Common use cases are:

```
var config = await _configsRepository.AsQueryable(x => x.Name.Equals("timeout")).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
var list = _configsRepository.AsQueryable().ToList();
```

`SingleOrDefaultAsync` works really fine. But `ToList` or even `ToListAsync` don't. I get the following error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'Entities.Domain.Config' type to  'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Entities.Domain.Config]' type is not valid

Can you please help me with my problem? I really need to use `AsQueryable` in that way.

I suppose that problem might be with

```
Expression = Expression.Constant(this);
```

in `EFQueryable` constructor. But what can I do with this?

In case of `AsQueryable().Where(expression)` I can create own extension method, but I simply can't create extension methods for every specific use case. I appreciate any help to make my implementation work

Comment: Something weird. What are you trying to achieve by this IQueryable implementation?  Asking because I know almost everything in this area and do not see benefits in this probe of realisation.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have a lot of legacy code on desktop which used DbContext as a constructor argument for Repository. When making some little changes I needed to re-write the generic repository, so it takes DbContextFactory as dependency instead of DbContext. legacy repositories has this weird AssQuerable with exposing logic outside of repository. I won't write such code nowadays, but atm I can't simply rewrite thousands of code lines. So I need to make this work

Comment: I tried the same implementation on .net 5 and EF Core. And it does work. So the problem is with EF 6 which I use in my .net framework application

Comment: I switched to EF Core 3.1 in .NET Framework 4.8 and it solved my issue.
Later I re-wrote the repository code to not use this Queryable